# elasticseach 2.4 : retrieve all records which are fulfilling all search criterias using scroll

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, scroll, nest

I am using elastic search for the first time and based on requirements i have some doubts and questions for scroll

To retrieve all data which are fulfilling all search criteria
1)I am trying to use scroll but i found while searching about it
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_21_search_changes.html
i found Search type scan is deprecated
but NEST is supporting it
so should i use "search type scan" or "sort by doc"? (I am using elastic search 2.4)

2)Can i use "sorting on any field" when using scrolling?

3)while doing clear scroll
 var test2 = client.ClearScroll(x=>x.ScrollId(results.ScrollId));

Getting error as below:
Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on DELETE: /_search/scroll

## Audit trail of this API call:

- [1] BadResponse: Node: http://mydomain@localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.0160110

  ## OriginalException: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
  at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TReturn](RequestData requestData) in C:\Users\russ\source\elasticsearch-net-2.x\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\HttpConnection.cs:line 141

  ## Request:

{"scroll_id":["c2NhbjswOzE7dG90YWxfaGl0czoxMjs="]}

## Response:

{}

so is it correct way of clearing scroll or not?

**Update:** : below is my code :

```
 List<Object> indexedList = new List<Object>();
    ISearchResponse<ListingSearch> listingResult =
            client.Search<ListingSearch>(search => search
                  .Index(Constant.ES_INDEX)                          
                  .Type(Constant.ES_TYPE)
                  .From(listingSearch.StartIndex)
                  .Size(10)
                  .Source(s => s.Include(i => i.Fields(outpputFields)))                         
                  .Query(query => query.
                            Bool(boolean => boolean.
                            Must(
                                must => must.Term(t => t.Field("is_deleted").Value(false))

                )
                 .Sort(x => x.Field("_doc", SortOrder.Ascending))                       
                .Scroll("60s")
                );
List<Object> indexedList = new List<Object>();
var results = client.Scroll<ListingSearch>("60s", listingResult.ScrollId);
                while (results.Documents.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var doc in results.Hits)
                    {
                        indexedList.Add(doc);
                    }

                    results = client.Scroll<ListingSearch>("60s", results.ScrollId);
                }


var test2 = client.ClearScroll(x=>x.ScrollId(results.ScrollId));
```

//Clear Scroll

With above code I am getting data 
but if i change size from 10 to 1000, getting no records.
Not sure if issue is the amount of data because my ES db has only 12-15 documents.

Answer (score 1):

NEST 2.x versions have `SearchType.Scan` because NEST 2.x versions are compatible with all Elasticsearch 2.x versions, so the search type needs to exist when using NEST 2.x against Elasticsearch 2.0. Sending the search type through in later versions won't have any effect.

The most efficient way of retrieving documents with scroll is sorting by `_doc` but you can specify any sort parameters when scrolling.

When using the scroll API, you should use the `scroll_id` from the previous request in the next scroll call to fetch the next set of results. Once you have finished with a scroll, it is a good idea to clear it by calling `ClearScroll()` as you are doing. Your call looks correct; perhaps the `scroll_id` has already expired at the point you make the clear call?

Comment: i have updated question with code. May i know how we can check if scroll_id is expired or not?
and 
"search type needs to exist when using NEST 2.x against Elasticsearch 2.0" - is ok to have search type and sort together as i have read that it can affect performance?

Comment: You can just make the `ClearScroll` call and handle the 404 Not Found response; thinking we may want to allow 404 as a valid response for `ClearScroll`. Specifying `search_type=scan` will be ignored in  in Elasticsearch 2.1.0+. Sorting by `_doc` will be most efficient, sorting by anything else will be less so. How much less is going to depend on a lot of factors.

Comment: thanks for your reply, ok will keep clear scroll and scan type also.
and one strange behavior i found , if i do not use "scan type" and pass size as 1000 then getting , no results as stated in question above.

Comment: Are you seeing this behaviour? http://stackoverflow.com/a/38494371/1831

Comment: No is little different ,1) i have not passed searchtype scan, sorted by _doc &2)size of records 10 It works . now if i change size to 1000 not work. and as a note my es has 10-15 records only. and once passing search type scan it works with both size 10 or 1000

Comment: hmm. Feel free to capture the request/response with fiddler and submit an issue if it looks like a bug: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues